# How can I start framer motion?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, framer-motion

I tried to make a modal window but I couldn't do it since framer doesn't seem to be working. I tried to use `animate={{color: "red"}}` and it worked but without animations, the text just became red.

Below, you can see the code which just moves the modal from top to almost the center.

```
import {motion} from 'framer-motion'

const modal = {
  hidden: {
    y: "-100vh",
    opacity: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    y: "200px",
    opacity: 1,
    transition: {delay: 0.5}
  }
}

<motion.div className="error-pop-up" variants={modal}>
  {error}
</motion.div>
```

It should go from top to almost center or something but it just doesn't do anything. I installed framer using yarn.

Answer (score 1):

In your motion component, you must specify which variant is assigned to initial and animate props.

```js
<motion.div className="error-pop-up" variants={modal} initial="hidden" animate="visible">
  {error}
</motion.div>
```

For modals I usually declare a useState and combine it with a ternary operator like this:

`const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false)`

```js
<motion.div className="error-pop-up" variants={modal} initial="hidden" animate={modalOpen ? "visible" : "hidden"}>
  {error}
</motion.div>
```